# I have some template related error during helm unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, open-telemetry

I have a helm chart with the following repository structure. It is basically a nested helm chart. The other helm chart is 'otel-collector' and the inner helm chart is 'opentelemetry-collector'

```
├── otel-collector
│   ├── Chart.lock
│   ├── Chart.yaml
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── charts
│   │   ├── opentelemetry-collector
│   │   │   ├── CONTRIBUTING.md
│   │   │   ├── Chart.yaml
│   │   │   ├── README.md
│   │   │   ├── UPGRADING.md
│   │   │   ├── ci
│   │   │   │   ├── clusterrole-values.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── config-override-values.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── daemonset-values.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── deployment-values.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── disabling-protocols-values.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── multiple-ingress-values.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── preset-clustermetrics-values.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── preset-hostmetrics-values.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── preset-kubeletmetrics-values.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── preset-kubernetesattributes-values.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── preset-logscollection-values.yaml
│   │   │   │   └── statefulset-values.yaml
│   │   │   ├── examples
│   │   │   │   ├── README.md
│   │   │   │   ├── daemonset-and-deployment
│   │   │   │   │   ├── daemonset-values.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   ├── deployment-values.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   └── rendered
│   │   │   │   │       ├── configmap-agent.yaml
│   │   │   │   │       ├── configmap.yaml
│   │   │   │   │       ├── daemonset.yaml
│   │   │   │   │       ├── deployment.yaml
│   │   │   │   │       ├── service.yaml
│   │   │   │   │       └── serviceaccount.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── daemonset-collector-logs
│   │   │   │   │   ├── rendered
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── configmap-agent.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── daemonset.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── serviceaccount.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   └── values.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── daemonset-hostmetrics
│   │   │   │   │   ├── rendered
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── configmap-agent.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── daemonset.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── serviceaccount.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   └── values.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── daemonset-lifecycle-hooks
│   │   │   │   │   ├── rendered
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── configmap-agent.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── daemonset.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── serviceaccount.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   └── values.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── daemonset-only
│   │   │   │   │   ├── rendered
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── configmap-agent.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── daemonset.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── serviceaccount.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   └── values.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── deployment-only
│   │   │   │   │   ├── rendered
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── configmap.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── deployment.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── service.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── serviceaccount.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   └── values.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── deployment-otlp-traces
│   │   │   │   │   ├── rendered
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── configmap.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── deployment.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── service.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── serviceaccount.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   └── values.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── deployment-use-existing-configMap
│   │   │   │   │   ├── deployment-values.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   └── rendered
│   │   │   │   │       ├── deployment.yaml
│   │   │   │   │       ├── service.yaml
│   │   │   │   │       └── serviceaccount.yaml
│   │   │   │   └── statefulset-only
│   │   │   │       ├── rendered
│   │   │   │       │   ├── configmap-statefulset.yaml
│   │   │   │       │   ├── service.yaml
│   │   │   │       │   ├── serviceaccount.yaml
│   │   │   │       │   └── statefulset.yaml
│   │   │   │       └── values.yaml
│   │   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   │   ├── NOTES.txt
│   │   │   │   ├── _config.tpl
│   │   │   │   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   │   │   │   ├── _pod.tpl
│   │   │   │   ├── clusterrole.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── clusterrolebinding.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── configmap-agent.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── configmap-statefulset.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── configmap.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── daemonset.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── deployment.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── hpa.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── ingress.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── pdb.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── podmonitor.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── prometheusrule.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── service.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── serviceaccount.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── servicemonitor.yaml
│   │   │   │   └── statefulset.yaml
│   │   │   ├── values.schema.json
│   │   │   └── values.yaml
│   │   └── opentelemetry-collector-0.47.0.tgz
│   ├── examples
│   │   ├── agent_gateway_mode.yaml
│   │   ├── agent_mode.yaml
│   │   └── gateway_mode.yaml
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── NOTES.txt
│   ├── test
│   │   ├── __snapshot__
│   │   ├── otel_agent_gateway_test.yaml
│   │   ├── otel_gateway_test.yaml
│   │   └── otel_only_agent_test.yaml
|---└── values.yaml
```

Now i am trying to perform helm unit testing. I have installed the following plugin:
`helm plugin install https://github.com/helm-unittest/helm-unittest`

I am currently testing the ./otel-collector/examples/gateway_mode.yaml using the test file otel_gateway_test.yaml

The otel_gateway_test.yaml files looks like this:
I have put the path of the deployment.yaml template of the inner helm chart folder: ../charts/gateway/templates/deployment.yaml

```
---
suite: deployment.yaml Validation
templates:
  - ../charts/gateway/templates/deployment.yaml
release:
  name: test-release
tests:
  - it: TC-01
    asserts:
      - equal:
          path: apiVersion
          value: apps/v1
  - it: TC-02
    asserts:
      - isKind:
          of: Deployment
```

Well there are more test cases (TC) but ive only shown a few here.

This is the command i use for running the helm unit tests:
`helm unittest -f test/otel_gateway_test.yaml otel-collector`
I am running this command from the outermost directory

These are the results of the test cases: Output

```
### Chart [ otel-collector ] otel-collector

 FAIL  deployment.yaml Validation   otel-collector/test/otel_gateway_test.yaml
    - TC-01
        Error: template: otel-collector/charts/gateway/templates/deployment.yaml:31:28: executing "otel-collector/charts/gateway/templates/deployment.yaml" at <include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") .>: error calling include: template: no template "otel-collector/charts/gateway/templates/configmap.yaml" associated with template "gotpl"

    - TC-02
        Error: template: otel-collector/charts/gateway/templates/deployment.yaml:31:28: executing "otel-collector/charts/gateway/templates/deployment.yaml" at <include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") .>: error calling include: template: no template "otel-collector/charts/gateway/templates/configmap.yaml" associated with template "gotpl"
```

Im assuming its an error with the ./otel-collector/charts/opentelemetrycollector/templates/deployment.yaml file

```
{{- if eq .Values.mode "deployment" -}}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "opentelemetry-collector.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "opentelemetry-collector.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- with .Values.annotations }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
spec:
{{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
{{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "opentelemetry-collector.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
      {{- include "opentelemetry-collector.component" . | nindent 6 }}
  strategy:
    {{- if eq .Values.rollout.strategy "RollingUpdate" }}
    {{- with .Values.rollout.rollingUpdate }}
    rollingUpdate:
      {{- toYaml . | nindent 6 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
    type: {{ .Values.rollout.strategy }}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
        {{- include "opentelemetry-collector.podAnnotations" . | nindent 8 }}
      labels:
        {{- include "opentelemetry-collector.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
        {{- include "opentelemetry-collector.component" . | nindent 8 }}
        {{- include "opentelemetry-collector.podLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
      {{- $podValues := deepCopy .Values }}
      {{- $podData := dict "Values" $podValues "configmapSuffix" "" "isAgent" false }}
      {{- include "opentelemetry-collector.pod" ($podData | mustMergeOverwrite (deepCopy .)) | nindent 6 }}
      hostNetwork: {{ .Values.hostNetwork }}
{{- end }}
```

After this i tried changing the path of the template to : `../charts/opentelemetry-collector/templates/deployment.yaml`

Then i ran 'helm unittest -f test/otel_gateway_test.yaml otel-collector' to do the helm unit testing again. And i got these results:

```
### Chart [ otel-collector ] otel-collector

 FAIL  deployment.yaml Validation   otel-collector/test/otel_gateway_test.yaml
    - TC-01

        - asserts[0] `equal` fail
            Error:
                template "otel-collector/charts/opentelemetry-collector/templates/deployment.yaml" not exists or not selected in test suite

    - TC-02

        - asserts[0] `isKind` fail
            Error:
                template "otel-collector/charts/opentelemetry-collector/templates/deployment.yaml" not exists or not selected in test suite
```

how do i get the helm unit testing to work , the templates are not being read correctly